# why does json seem not to handle a object that has fairly large data properly

Tags: python, json

am working on a kivy app that uses a threaded socket server,to send and recieve message from a database, when i use json in my code to load data that just short, such as the sql statement below that selects just a target person from a database, i get no errors

```
import json
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("DataBase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE Username='williz'",)
rows=cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
list_ = []
for i in rows:
    list_.append(i)
m = str.encode(json.dumps(list_))
print(m)
```

But when i change this same code sql statement, to select much more data such as ("SELECT * FROM Profile"), i get the error

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/MyProject1/schoolproject/new.py", line 148, in run
    command = json.loads(command)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This only happens just as the data am trying to get gets larger, and i really dont know a way around it

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from a different part of the source code, not the example you've posted. The issue is on the line 148 in your new.py file, when running `json.loads`. Can you post your whole code? Are you maybe manipulating the data differently?

Comment: @Milan Cermak ,yes the error isnt really from the code i posted,that code was just to explain the concept that produces the error, cos if i were to post everything that will be quite a lot of code, but as i explained earlier, (using my code above as example)the error only comes up when the data is large, but same will go through smoothly if i reduced the data.My exact issue is if i were to get every user data in my database it will throw the above error,but say i get just a persons, or say i limit query to 3/4 user, then i get no errors. or could it be socket module cos my app is sever/client